# Calculator doesn't display result

Tags: javascript

*This calculator is only for one digit calculations

In my code there are 3 textboxes Two for values and one for Operators.

I want that if first textbox isn't empty and user clicks on any number than that value should be added in another textbox.

When I click Enter it doesn't display result and I didn't show  any kind of error in console

```
// Textboxes, Enter and Reset
    var txt1 = document.querySelector("#txt1");
    var txt2 = document.querySelector("#txt2");
    var txt3 = document.querySelector("#txt3");
    var ent = document.querySelector("#ent");
    var res = document.querySelector("#res");

    // Number-Buttons
    var b1 = document.querySelector("#b1");
    var b2 = document.querySelector("#b2");
    var b3 = document.querySelector("#b3");
    var b4 = document.querySelector("#b4");
    var b5 = document.querySelector("#b");
    var b6 = document.querySelector("#b6");
    var b7 = document.querySelector("#b7");
    var b8 = document.querySelector("#b8");
    var b9 = document.querySelector("#b9");

    // Operators
    var add = document.querySelector("#add");
    var sub = document.querySelector("#sub");
    var mul = document.querySelector("#mul");
    var div = document.querySelector("#div");

    if (txt1.value == "") {
        function B1() { txt1.value = "1" }
        function B2() { txt1.value = "2" }
        function B3() { txt1.value = "3" }
        function B4() { txt1.value = "4" }
        function B5() { txt1.value = "5" }
        function B6() { txt1.value = "6" }
        function B7() { txt1.value = "7" }
        function B8() { txt1.value = "8" }
        function B9() { txt1.value = "9" }

        if (txt2.value == "") {
            function Add() { txt2.value = "+" }
            function Sub() { txt2.value = "-" }
            function Mul() { txt2.value = "*" }
            function Div() { txt2.value = "/" }
        }

        // if (txt1.value != "" && txt3.value == "") {
        //  function B1() { txt3.value = "1" }
        //  function B2() { txt3.value = "2" }
        //  function B3() { txt3.value = "3" }
        //  function B4() { txt3.value = "4" }
        //  function B5() { txt3.value = "5" }
        //  function B6() { txt3.value = "6" }
        //  function B7() { txt3.value = "7" }
        //  function B8() { txt3.value = "8" }
        //  function B9() { txt3.value = "9" }
        // }
    } 

    function Ent() {

        if (txt1.value == "" || txt2.value == "" || txt3.value == "") {
            alert("Pls Enter values and select the operator");
        }

        function sum() {
            if (txt2.value == "+") {
                var Sum = Number(txt1.value) + Number(txt3.value);
                alert(Sum);
                console.log(Sum);
            }
        }

        function sub() {
            if (txt2.value == "-") {
                var Sub = Number(txt1.value) - Number(txt3.value);
                alert(Sub);
                console.log(Sub);
            }
        }

        function mul() {
            if (txt2.value == "*") {
                var Mul = Number(txt1.value) * Number(txt3.value);
                alert(Mul);
                console.log(Mul);
            }
        }

        function div() {
            if (txt2.value == "/") {
                var Div = Number(txt1.value) / Number(txt3.value);
                alert(Div);
                console.log(Div);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you "click enter"?  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] as a code snippet?

Comment: you may not see any type of error in your console, but we can't verify it and therefore assess your question.

Comment: ok but is there any mistake in my code or logic ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand what you want to do from the code you shared. In the solution you developed, I made subtractions as the numbers are defined as separate buttons. In this direction, I developed a lean solution. This program is used as follows:

1. Use the numeric keypad to enter the first number.
2. Click the action you want to perform (+, -, *, /)
3. Use the numeric keypad to enter the second number.
4. Click the **CALCULATE** button to see the result.
5. Click the **CLEAR** button to clear the screen.

[image]

```js
var firstNumberText = document.getElementById("txt1");
var secondNumberText = document.getElementById("txt2");
var operatorText = document.getElementById("txt3");
var operationText = document.getElementById("txt4");
var resultText = document.getElementById("txt5");

var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
var subButton = document.getElementById("sub");
var mulButton = document.getElementById("mul");
var divButton = document.getElementById("div");

var enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");

let status = true;
let currentFirstNumber = "";
let currentSecondNumber = "";

function updateText(){
  firstNumberText.innerText = currentFirstNumber;
  secondNumberText.innerText = currentSecondNumber;
}

function changeState(operator) {
  operatorText.innerText = operator;
  status = !status;
}

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeState("+");
});

subButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeState("-");
});

mulButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeState("*");
});

divButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeState("/");
});

function numberPressed(pressedButton) {
  if(status) 
    currentFirstNumber += pressedButton.value;
  else
    currentSecondNumber += pressedButton.value;
}

function updateResult(result, operator) {
  operationText.innerText = firstNumberText.textContent + operator + secondNumberText.textContent + "=" + `${result}`;
  resultText.innerText = result;
}

function calculate() { 
  if (firstNumberText.value == "" || secondNumberText.value == "" || operatorText.value == "") {
      alert("Warning");
      return;
  }
  
  var result = 0;
  
  if(operatorText.textContent == "+") {
    result = parseInt(firstNumberText.textContent) + parseInt(secondNumberText.textContent);
    updateResult(result, "+");
  }
  else if(operatorText.textContent == "-") {
    result = parseInt(firstNumberText.textContent) - parseInt(secondNumberText.textContent);
    updateResult(result, "-");
  }
  else if(operatorText.textContent == "*") {
    result = parseInt(firstNumberText.textContent) * parseInt(secondNumberText.textContent);
    updateResult(result, "*");
  }
  else if(operatorText.textContent == "/") {
    result = parseInt(firstNumberText.textContent) / parseInt(secondNumberText.textContent);
    updateResult(result, "/");
  }
}

enterButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  calculate();
});

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  status = true;
  currentFirstNumber = "";
  currentSecondNumber = "";
  firstNumberText.innerText = "";
  secondNumberText.innerText = "";
  operatorText.innerText = "";
  operationText.innerText = "";
  resultText.innerText = "";
});
```

```html
<!-- First Number -->
<label id="txt1">-</label><br>

<!-- Operator -->
<label id="txt3">-</label><br>

<!-- Second Number -->
<label id="txt2">-</label><br>

<!-- Operation -->
<label id="txt4">-</label><br>

<!-- Result -->
<label id="txt5">-</label><br>

<button type="button" value="0" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>0</button>
<button type="button" value="1" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>1</button>
<button type="button" value="2" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>2</button>
<button type="button" value="3" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>3</button>
<button type="button" value="4" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>4</button>
<button type="button" value="5" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>5</button>
<button type="button" value="6" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>6</button>
<button type="button" value="7" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>7</button>
<button type="button" value="8" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>8</button>
<button type="button" value="9" onclick='numberPressed(this);updateText()'>9</button>
<br><br>

<button type="button" id="add">+</button>
<button type="button" id="sub">-</button>
<button type="button" id="mul">*</button>
<button type="button" id="div">/</button><br><br>

<button type="button" id="enter">CALCULATE</button>
<button type="button" id="clear">CLEAR</button>
```